# The size of the generated confusion matrix using confusionmat function is not right, why?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, svm

I am working on a traffic sign recognition code in MATLAB using Belgian Traffic Sign Dataset. This dataset can be found [here](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~timofter/).

The dataset consists of training data and test data (or evaluation data).

I resized the given images and extracted HOG features using the `VL_HOG` function from VL_feat library.

Then, I trained a multi class SVM using all of the signs inside the training dataset. There are **62** categories (i.e. different types of traffic signs) and 4577 frames inside the training set.

I used the `fitcecoc` function to obtain the classifier.

Upon training the multi-class SVM, I want to test the classifier performance using the test data and I used the `predict` and `confusionmat` functions, respectively.

For some reason, the size of the returned confusion matrix is 53 by 53 instead of 62 by 62.

Why the size of the confusion matrix is not the same as the number of categories?

Comment: Your test data probably does not contain 62 classes. You can check that by doing `unique(y_test)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the folders inside the testing dataset are empty, causing MATLAB to skip those rows and columns in the confusion matrix.